# Drupal 7 -> 8 migration of a large database takes forever

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-8

So I have a Drupal 7 database with 2 million users that need to move to Drupal 8 with a minimum of downtime (target is an hour). The Drupal migrate module appears to solve this problem, but it writes new rows one item at a time and in my tests, 4 thousand users + related data took 20 minutes on frankly beastly AWS instances. Extrapolating to the full dataset, it would take me 7 days to run the migration, and that amount of downtime is not reasonable.

I've made a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2890011) against Drupal core but I also wanted to see if the community has any ideas that I missed. Also, I want to spawn some discussion about this issue.

Comment: Do you need to move the entire database or only the users? Else you can dump the necessary tables (or entire db, but be prepared for a dump of several gigabytes). Create a new database, import the dump into your new database and then change your site credentials to use the new database. Pretty new to Drupal btw, so this might all be crap :p

Comment: The way that the users are stored has changed between Drupal 7 and Drupal 8. Every user needs to have some logic done to them before they can be put into the new DB :)

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. Maybe you can write your own migration script? Take a look into the Migration Module and write your own script. You can still follow my first comment, but instead of dumping and importing you would be reading and outputting via your script.

Comment: I mean, thats what I am doing right now. It does require me to re-implement the entity save logic, but as a bulk SQL request. I was hoping that there was a better way.

Comment: Maybe there is, but I wouldn't know it..

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still cares about this, I have resolved this issue. Further research showed that not only does the Drupal migration module write new rows one at a time, but it also reads rows from the source one at a time. Further, for each row Drupal will write to a mapping table for the source table so that it can support rollback and update.

Since a user's data is stored in one separate table per custom field, this results in something like 8 reads and 16 writes for each user.

I ended up extending Drupal's Migration Executable for running the process. Then I overrode both the part that reads data and the part that writes it to do their work in batches, and to not write to the mapping tables. I believe that my projected time is now down to less then an hour (A speed up of 168 times!).

Still, trying to use the Drupal infrastructure was more trouble then it was worth. If you are doing this yourself just write a command line application and do the SQL queries manually.